# Simple Nested Attribute Association issue Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, rails-activerecord

I have two models, a User model and a Hair Model. I have created a form that successfully allows a user to submit and save their name, location in the user model and hair color in the hair model.

What I can't seem to work out is how to retrieve the user's hair color in my views?

Hair is currently a nested attribute of User in my routes and the current result I am being shown by the view is `Rosie Ealing #<Hair:0x4d5e078>`

Any help that can be offered really would be much appreciated.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :hair, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hair
  attr_accessible :location, :name, :hair_attributes
end
```

**Hair Model**

```
class Hair < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :color, :user_id
end
```

**User Index**

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %>
    <%= user.location %>
    <%= user.hair %>
<% end %>
```

**User Model Migration**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :location

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Hair Model Migration**

```
class CreateHairs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :hairs do |t|
      t.string :color
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_hair
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
            redirect_to users_path
        else
            render "user/new"
        end
  end

  def index
    @user = User.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %>
    <%= user.location %>
    <%= user.hair.color %>
<% end %>
```

Your code is return a link to the object Hair, rather the the data contained in it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately I tried this and it gives me and error `undefined method 'color' for nil:NilClass` - any idea what I could do to fix this? :)

Comment: Ha! I am a fool it's because I had 5 users created without a hair association (from when I was trying to get the association to work). Now that I have deleted these rows in the database it has worked! Thanks for your help :)